# How do I make XAML DataGridColumns fill the entire DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpf-controls

I am using DataGrids in XAML (not Silverlight) with resizable columns, the DataGrid will expand if the user resizes the screen.

Currently if the widths of all the DataGrid columns are less than the width of the DataGrid I get an extra "column" appearing which is unclickable and serves no purpose.

Does anyone know how to make one column always resize to fill all the remaining space?

Answer (score 290, accepted):

If you use `Width="*"` the column will fill to expand the available space.

If you want all columns to divide the grid equally apply this to all columns. If you just want one to fill the remaining space just apply it to that column with the rest being "Auto" or a specific width.

You can also use `Width="0.25*"` (for example) if you want the column to take up 1/4 of the available width.

Comment: and how to do similar thing if i'm using `AutoGenerateColumns="True"`?

Comment: @javapowered - I'd suggest asking your own question, referencing this one.

Comment: @javapowered `<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" ColumnWidth="*" ItemsSource={Binding} />`

Comment: note: if for some reason, after setting ColumnWidth to "*" you dont see any effect, change the ItemsSource for a second and then undo it - the designer has to be kicked to reload the data, or else the columns may stay stale and dont notice the new style.

Comment: @MohamedSakherSawan it does indeed work for datagrid. Both `ColumnWidth="*"` on the _DataGrid_ and `Width="*"` on the indivdual columns have the desired effect

Comment: Gives an Error Sting cannot be converted to '*'

Comment: @Steve it works only if you set width on DataGrid itself.

Comment: @co2f2e did u do it inside DataGridTextColumn (Sorry it late but i see nobody replied your Error)      ==>                                                                                                                                                                          <DataGrid >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ColumnTitle1"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="0.25*"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ColumnTitle3" Width="0.25*"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>

Comment: If the datagrid width changes, the column width will not update the layout immediately.update only when ItemsSource is added or deleted

Answer (score 21):

Make sure your DataGrid has `Width` set to something like `{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=Window,AncestorLevel=1}}`.

Like that, your setting of `Width="*"` attribute on `DataGrid.Columns/DataGridXXXXColumn` elements should work.

Answer (score 15):

As noted, the `ColumnWidth="*"` worked perfectly well for a DataGrid in XAML.

I used it in this context:

```
<DataGrid ColumnWidth="*" ItemsSource="{Binding AllFolders, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Answer (score 8):

My 2 Cent ->

Very late to party

DataGrid -> Column -> Width="*" only work if DataGrid parent container has fix width.

example : i put the DataGrid in Grid -> Column whose width="Auto" then Width="*" in DataGrid does not work but if you set Grid -> Column Width="450" mean fixed then it work fine

Answer (score 7):

Set the columns `Width` property to be a proportional width such as `*`

Answer (score 3):

Another spin on the same theme:

```
protected void OnWindowSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    dataGrid.Width = e.NewSize.Width - (e.NewSize.Width * .1);

    foreach (var column in dataGrid.Columns)
    {
       column.Width = dataGrid.Width / dataGrid.Columns.Count;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I added a HorizontalAlignment="Center" (The default is "Strech") and it solved my problem because it made the datagrid only as wide as needed. (Removed the datagrid's Width setting if you have one.)

[image]

Comment: Combined with the selected answer and this one it solved the problem for me. I needed to remove the width on the Datagrid itself. Thanks.

Comment: In my case the accepted answer also wasn't enough. After adding `HorizontalAlignment="Center"` like you mentioned, it fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This will not expand the last column of the xaml grid to take the remaining space if 
`AutoGeneratedColumns="True"`.

Comment: I have removed the AutoGenerateColumns, even though the columns are not divided or stretched the entire width of the data grid/screen. I have the corresponding row of the grid to be "*" and the columns width does not have any width specified (either "auto" or "some value"). But still I am having the issues, here is the xaml code of my design http://pastie.org/10085815

Answer (score 0):

set ONE column's width to any value, i.e. width="*"

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a C# workaround:

If you need for some reason to have the "AutoGeneratedColumns" enabled, one thing you can do is to specify all the columns's width except the ones you want to be auto resized (it will **not take the remaining space**, but it will **resize to the cell's content**).

Example (dgShopppingCart is my DataGrid):

```
dgShoppingCart.Columns[0].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; 
dgShoppingCart.Columns[1].Header = "Qty";
dgShoppingCart.Columns[1].Width = 100;
dgShoppingCart.Columns[2].Header = "Product Name"; /*This will be resized to cell content*/
dgShoppingCart.Columns[3].Header = "Price";
dgShoppingCart.Columns[3].Width = 100;
dgShoppingCart.Columns[4].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

For me it works as a workaround because I needed to have the DataGrid resized when the user maximize the Window.

Answer (score 0):

****It worked well for me,** just put columnwidth dependency property as `columnwidth="*"`** it will fill columns widths to datagrid width like as winforms(autosize=fill)

```
 <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="dg1" VerticalAlignment="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0,0,-6,0" Width="1520" Height="700"  CanUserAddRows="True" 
        
        CanUserDeleteRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeData}" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="DarkBlue" VerticalGridLinesBrush="DarkGreen" ColumnWidth="*" >
```

Answer (score 0):

To stretch a control across multiple columns, just set the Column span to match the number of columns defined for the grid.

Grid.ColumnSpan="12"