# Shrinking the width of a column in WPF for DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My first row looks something like this:

```
Title 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ...
```

If I choose

```
ColumnWidth="Auto"
```

it sizes it correctly, but there is too much space between the columns.  Is there a way to shrink that? I tried in the code behind my xaml where I get the data to do

```
if (textColumn != 0) {
textColumn.Width = 8;
}
```

or something along those lines, but the size doesn't seem to change.  I'm not sure if this is correct as I'm new to WPF and C#.  Thanks.

Edit:

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dtGridReads"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"                                       
        VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode ="Standard"
          EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
          EnableRowVirtualization="True"
        ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"
        CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="True"
         ItemsSource ="{Binding}" Block.TextAlignment="Center"
         AlternatingRowBackground="LightGoldenrodYellow" RowBackground="White"
          CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" FrozenColumnCount="1"
           GridLinesVisibility="None" Style="{StaticResource ConcensusDataGridStyle}" FontSize="12" >
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: why don't you do it in your xaml, if your doing MVVM you can databind it so you don't use the code behind. btw You can do it by percentages too! If you paste your code maybe I can help you more

Comment: Not sure how to do it in the XAML as the first column is different than the other columns.  I posted my code to see if that helps troubleshoot.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you want to go below "the minimum width" of a `DataGridColumn`. There seems to be some sort of restriction built into the `DataGrid` on how small a `DataGridColumn` can become. I tried looking at this with reflector but couldn't find the source of this. Also tried changing every single column header, thumb, textblock etc. with Snoop but that didn't help either

Comment: i used this also to fill the grid with all coumns.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028894/how-do-i-make-xaml-datagrid-columns-fill-the-entire-datagrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a column width converter class and pass in a value to the converter to set your size accordingly.

Here is the converter

```
 private const double StaticGridWidth = 602;


public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    if ((value != null) && (parameter != null))
    {
        double newValue = (double)value - StaticGridWidth;
        double dparam = double.Parse(parameter.ToString());
        double width = newValue * (dparam/1000);
        return (width > 0) ? width : 0;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Here is the usage in XAML

```
<Converters:WidthConverter x:Key="widthConvert" />

<GridViewColumn Header="{Binding TypeColumnHeader}"  
                                Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=treeGrid, Converter={StaticResource widthConvert}, ConverterParameter=190}" 

                            />
```

Note that the values you pass in must be whole numbers if you are building a regional application.  If you are using decimals in xaml and the local uses , for the decimal - it will EXPLODE.

Comment: Note that the static grid width is to account for columns in my grid that I set a static width for.  This allows you to mix the static / dynamic column widths in the same grid and hopefully avoid the scroll bar by default.

Answer (score 0):

Theres numerous ways to do this.

1. First you would need to create a column for every column.

So ie. from MSDN

```
<sdk:DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid4" 
    Height="160" Margin="0,5,0,10" 
    RowHeight="40" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >    
    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn 
            Header="First Name" 
            Width="SizeToHeader"
            Binding="{Binding FirstName}" 
            FontSize="20" />
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn 
            Header="Last Name" 
            Width="SizeToCells"
            Binding="{Binding LastName}" 
            FontSize="20" />
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn 
            Header="Address"
            Width="150"
            Binding="{Binding Address}" >
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
                </Style>
            </sdk:DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
                </Style>
            </sdk:DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        </sdk:DataGridTextColumn>
        <sdk:DataGridCheckBoxColumn 
            Header="New?" 
            Width="40"
            Binding="{Binding IsNew}" />
        <sdk:DataGridCheckBoxColumn 
            Header="Subscribed?" 
            Width="Auto"
            Binding="{Binding IsSubscribed}" 
            IsThreeState="True" />
    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</sdk:DataGrid>
```

SizeToHeader means that it's going to size up based on how long the header is
on width you can also do something like
width="8" which means you are hard coding the value of the width in as 8

You can also do it as percentages

so lets say you have 3 columns
one column width you want .3* , next you want .5* and next you want .2* makes up 100% of the datagrid. you can say it as
width=".5*";

You can also bind the width to some sort of property In your viewmodel if you want for it to change, in addition you can also do what tsells states and run it through a converter.